# Using Bind at PDO

Tags: php, parameters, pdo

I am confused about Bind using! Is there any difference between those two codes below?

```
$stmt->bindValue( ":password", $password, PDO::PARAM_INT );

$stmt->bindParam(':password',$password);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [PHP.Net](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php),

> Unlike PDOStatement::bindValue(), the variable is bound as a reference
>   and will only be evaluated at the time that PDOStatement::execute() is
>   called.

so using bindParam(), if you change the variable before calling execute(), it will use the changed value. bindValue(), will evaluate it immediately and use that value not caring about any changes after calling bindValue() but before execute().